# SQL Server: How to query within a string?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement where my client wants me to retrieve specific information from a text column

Following is the sample of the same

```
the student scored following result:     class: 6            subject:            result:    english               80       math         23
```

science         45

The expected outcome needs to be like -

```
English        Maths          Science
80             23             45
```

I tried using string_split

```
select value from STRING_SPLIT( (select value from mytable where [student roll number] = 'SCH-01097') , ' ' )
```

but that only split the value into multiple rows that can't be queried.

I also tried using LTRIM with CHARINDEX approach, but the column have different text and not always organized. the initial text is different most of the time.

can this be done?

edit   - I am close but just not there yet

So far I have reached here

```
SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT ((select 
        substring(value, charindex('Block',value),1000)
                     from mytable where [rollnumber ] = 'SCH-01097'),' ') WHERE VALUE <> ' '
```

this gives me everything I need but in a single column

```
class6:
Subject
result
english
80
math
23
science
45
```

now how to make it in desired table form?

Comment: `rows that can't be queried` - why not? They can. Add `where value <> ''` for convenience.

Comment: So far I have reached here

SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT ((select 
  substring(value, charindex('Block',value),1000)
         from mytable where [rllnumber ] = 'SCH-01097'),' ') WHERE VALUE <> ' '


this gives me everything I need but in a single column

class6:
Subject
result
english
80
math
23
science
45


now how to make it in desired table form?

Comment: Are the subject always present and always in the same order? Or can the subjects and/or the order vary from row to row?

Comment: No, Sometimes subjects are missing, sometimes written in short form like 'EN' for english. luckily, these are the only two ways they have written.

But order is always same - like English, maths and science

The biggest problem I am facing is that the SQL picks EN from anywhere, 

example - exam ENded on friday.    The query picks the EN from there too 

(collation is case insensitive)

Comment: From [`String_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "The output rows might be in any order. The order is _not_ guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain the order of the split values this answer uses [DelimitedSplit8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function).  Something like this works.

[Edit] Instead of having specific strings in a CTE, the query now uses 'stems' to map multiple strings to the same class.  For example, if English is entered as En it will still be mapped to English.

Table and data

```
drop table if exists #tTest;
go
create table #tTest(
  string        Varchar(256));
  
insert #tTest(string) values
('the student scored following result:     class: 6            subject:            result:    english               80       math         23');
```

DelimitedSplit8k

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DelimitedSplit8K
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

Query

```
;with 
stems_cte(stem, word) as (
    select 'English', 'English' union all
    select 'En', 'English' union all
    select 'Math', 'Math' union all
    select 'Maths', 'Math' union all
    select 'Science', 'Science'),
splt_cte(string, str_val, ndx, lead_ndx, lead_len, rn) as (
    select t.string, ds.Item, charndx.ndx,
           lead(charndx.ndx) over (order by ds.ItemNumber),
           lead(len(ds.[Item])) over (order by ds.ItemNumber),
           ItemNumber
    from #tTest t
         cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t.string, ' ') ds
         cross apply (select charindex(ds.Item, t.string, 1) ndx) charndx
    where Item <> ' '),
spec_rows_cte(word, ndx, lead_ndx, lead_len, rn) as (
    select sp.word, sc.ndx, sc.lead_ndx, sc.lead_len, sc.rn 
    from splt_cte sc
         join stems_cte sp on sc.str_val=sp.stem)
select max(case when src.word='English' then substring(sc.string, src.lead_ndx, src.lead_len) else null end) English,
       max(case when src.word='Math' then substring(sc.string, src.lead_ndx, src.lead_len) else null end) Math,
       max(case when src.word='Science' then substring(sc.string, src.lead_ndx, src.lead_len) else null end) Science
from splt_cte sc
     join spec_rows_cte src on sc.rn=src.rn;
```

Output

```
English Math    Science
80      23      NULL
```

Comment: this works really well... but there is just one problem. some rows have EN instead of english. Is there any way to address that? The situation shows up when there is a word that contains EN. this affects the output

Comment: Ah fixed it. Just added '(space)EN(space)'

Comment: I updated with a 'stems' table.  Multiple representations of the same word can be mapped to the preferred word

Comment: I have tested it and it works, but now I have run into a new problem.

in one of the rows, its written like "English score is 78"

so the output comes out as 

English  Math Science
Score     87     60

Comment: In the question there's only a single sample record and the pattern as you described.  From my perspective the code addresses the data I can see.  You're referencing data which is not available to me

Comment: I agree, even I was surprised to see people are filling data like this. there are more than 10k rows and I didn't know if this scenario can pop up.

Comment: If I may suggest a course of action.  Analyze the 10k rows and determine the full list of stems and patterns however it's appropriate (with 1 or more words and/or SQL '%', _, etc wildcarded patterns).  Then ask a new question.

Comment: I'd suggest processing the data outside of sql. This is a mixture of natural language parsing and dirty data scraping. Doing that in SQL is nuts.

Answer (score -1):

You can insert the results from your query into a table variable with an Identity column, then get the next row for each required subset:

```
declare @tmp table (Id int identity, Value varchar(20))

Insert into @tmp (VALUE)
SELECT  VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT ((select 
        substring(value, charindex('Block',value),1000)
                     from mytable where [rollnumber ] = 'SCH-01097'),' ') WHERE VALUE <> ' '
        
select  
         English = (Select top 1 Value From @tmp where Id = (Select Id + 1 From @tmp where Value = 'english')),
         Math = (Select top 1 Value From @tmp where Id = (Select Id + 1 From @tmp where Value = 'math')),
         Science = (Select top 1 Value From @tmp where Id = (Select Id + 1 From @tmp where Value = 'science'))
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: The docs for `SPLIT_STRING()` specifically state that the order of the rows is NOT guaranteed... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: this works when predicate is just one rollnumber for some rollnumbers (not all). But when I place a cursor to check more than one student, it fails.